# How can I change the current repository I am connected to?

Tags: git, github

I've deleted my repository on GitHub and try to create one local.

When I do:   `remote show origin`
Result is:

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/userName/repositoryName.git/' not found
```

Comment: I'd suggest reading the [git book section on working with remotes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes)

Comment: @NickTomlin thank you, I'll definitely have a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a new remote available you can update the URL used by the origin remote.

```
git remote set-url origin <your new remote URL or path>
```

If you do not have an associated remote you can simply remove the current origin remote.

```
git remote rm origin
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
git config remote.origin.url <your new repository URL>
```